# HeaderLeft onPress to open the drawer, undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I am having a problem with my line of code specifically with the headerLeft onPress. I wanted to put an icon where when pressed it will open the drawerNavigator of my simple application.

this is my AppNavigation.js

```
//DRAWER NAVIGATOR
const drawerNav = createDrawerNavigator({
  JobFeed: {
screen: MainScreen,
navigationOptions: {drawerLabel: 'Job Feed',}
  },
},
{
  drawerPosition : "left",   contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
});

// Manifest of possible screens
const primaryNav = createStackNavigator({
  LaunchScreen: { 
screen: LaunchScreen,
navigationOptions: {
  title: "Ty, Next",
  headerTitleStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: 'CoreSansD65Heavy',
    color: Colors.semiGray,
  }
}
   },

MainScreen: {
        screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: "Ty, Next",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            flex: 1,
            fontFamily: 'CoreSansD65Heavy',
            color: Colors.semiGray,
            marginBottom: 20,
      }
    }
  },
}, 
{
  // Default config for all screens
  initialRouteName: 'MainScreen',
})
```

so here's the problem. In my MainScreen.js I put this code, whenever I press the button It is saying that undefined is not an object (evaluating _this2.props.navigation ) Please help me I am stuck on this particular matter..

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state } = navigation;
    const {} = state;
    return {
        headerStyle:{
            backgroundColor: "Transparent",
            marginRight: 20,
            marginLeft: 20,
        }, 
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}>
                    <Icon name="bars" color={Colors.red} size={30}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerLeftStyle: styles.drawerIcon,
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Icon2 name="sc-telegram" color={Colors.red} size={30} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerRightStyle: styles.planeIcon,
        headerTransparent:  true,
    };
}
```

Also I can't even access my drawer navigator when swiping to right. Any Ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Try changing the onPress to `onPress={navigation.openDrawer()}`

Comment: @Andrew I tried it and its saying undefined is not a function (evaluating navigation.openDrawer() )

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my declaration for drawerNavigator

Answer (score 0):

In your mainscreen.js is your component is class based component if it is try to create a fat arrow function instead of directly calling on onpress prop and call from that function and if your component is not class based make it first..!